# Why FilteredTextBoxExtender is not working after PostBack on dynamically created TextBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm creating TextBoxes dynamically on one button click.

Below is the code which is used for this purpose.

```
var textBox =  new TextBox()
{
    ID = i
};
var filteredTextBoxExtender = new FilteredTextBoxExtender()
{
    TargetControlID = textBox.ID,
    FilterType = FilterTypes.Numbers | FilterTypes.LowercaseLetters | FilterTypes.UppercaseLetters     
 };

  subDiv.Controls.Add(textBox);
  subDiv.Controls.Add(filteredTextBoxExtender);
```

On Some Other second Button click , same way I'm creating textboxes dynamically. but with different id(id is handled by modifying value of i variable).
Functionality is working fine, but filteredTextBoxExtender FilterType is not working.

Please let me know what could be the issue and how to solver it.

Observation: In firebug I get the following exception.

```
Error: Sys.ArgumentException: Value must not be null for Controls and Behaviors. 
Parameter name: element
```

when user click on second button.

User is able to enter special characters and spaces, but I dont want to allow him.

Comment: try assigning Id of FilteredTextBoxExtender as well.

Comment: I think your error is for the targetControlId of filteredTextBoxExtender is not setting properly as it may not be able to find the textbox properly as the textbox hasn't rendered yet.

Comment: But what is the solution ?

Answer (score -1):

the new `filteredTextBoxExtender` doesn't have ID attribute assigned